# How to have eclipse create .classpath,.settings files in a different folder other than source code folder?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I was trying something like below:

```
- I created a workspace under "C:\workspace"
- I created a sourcecode folder under "C:\sourcecode\maven_project_1"
- I opened eclipse with the workspace
- I imported maven_project_1 as maven project using the option "Import existing maven project".
- I expected 
    - the project would get imported. This happened right.
    - the eclipse files i.e. .classpath, .settings etc would get created under "C:\workspace\maven_project_1" but they are created under "C:\sourcecode\maven_project_1" instead.
```

Is there a way to have the files get created under "C:\workspace\maven_project_1"?

This way I feel the sourcecode would be free from eclipse settings.

Please suggest the right way to do this if possible. Thank You.

Comment: The file with the `pom.xml` file is the Maven *project* folder. The `src` subfolder is the *source code* folder. Eclipse creates its project files in the *project* folder, as it should.

Comment: The `.classpath` file and the `.settings` folder are intended to be shared and therefore located in the project folder. In Maven and Gradle projects the `.classpath` file can be excluded from sharing since it can be created from the `pom.xml` file. The `.settings` folder, on the other hand, contains project-specific settings that cannot be derived from the `pom.xml` file and should therefore be shared (not sharing existing project-specific settings does not make sense, does it?).

Comment: "not sharing existing project-specific settings does not make sense, does it". Well in principle you are right. But in many teams only some developers use Eclipse while others may be using other things, and I have often heard the opinion in those circumstances that the team does not want IDE-specific metadata to be put in the shared source code repository.

Comment: "Please suggest the right way to do this if possible." I don't think there is any way. Eclipse will create these files inside the project folder. That is just how it works and I don't think this is something you can change. The best you can probably do is to avoid sharing these files with other team members via source control by excluding them, for example, via the `.gitignore` file, assuming that you are using git.